# NSString finding a word and the next word in a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I've got a `NSString *paragraph;` which is filled with N number of words.  In there I'm guaranteed to have:

> ...
>       First Name: David
>       Last Name: Johnson
>       ...

What I need to do is find David and Johnson out of this string. However I don't know what the name is ahead of time (David could be John, Chris, etc..)

In C# I'd just find the line starting with First Name: and then separate the words with a " " as a delimiter.. But I'm lost on how to do this in Objective-C

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Like this:

```
NSString *lastName;
NSString *firstName;
NSString *text = @"Foobar\nFirst Name: David\nLast Name: Johnson\nFoobaz\nBarBaz";

NSScanner *textScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:text];

if ([textScanner scanUpToString:@"\nFirst Name: " intoString:NULL]) {
    [textScanner scanString:@"First Name: " intoString:NULL];
    [textScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&firstName];
}

// if last name always comes after first name there's no need to do this:
[textScanner setScanLocation:0];

if ([textScanner scanUpToString:@"\nLast Name: " intoString:NULL]) {
    [textScanner scanString:@"Last Name: " intoString:NULL];
    [textScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&lastName];
}    

NSLog(@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName);
```

Comment: I would love to hear why I shouldn't use NSScanner for this task, because I use them quite a lot.

Comment: I think one **should** use NSScanner for this, this is why I marked your answer as useful and I think it should be the accepted answer. +1 means my approval for the smart solution, just like [Google +1 button](http://www.google.com/+1/button/) :-)

Comment: Yeah I know, but somebody else downvoted it ;-) Should have made that clearer

Comment: This approach was very fast and solved my issues. Never knew about NSScanner. It was HTML that I was reading in so I used: [textScanner scanUpToString:@"<br />" intString... instead

Answer (score 2):

First split the string based on lines using `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
NSArray* lines = [paragraph compontentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Then you can filter out which lines start with First Name

```
NSPredicate* firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith 'First Name:'"];
NSArray* filteredArray = [lines filteredArrayUsingPredicate:firstNamePredicate];
```

Then you can split based on spaces and look for the word following the "Name:" token.